# How to update current values inside an angular.forEach()?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to convert a portion of an object's values from integer values 1 or 0 to boolean values true or false.

The structure is as follows:

```
angular.forEach(a.b.c, function (options) {
    ...
    angular.forEach(options, function (value, option) {
        if (value == 0) {
            option = false;
        } else {
            option = true;
        }
        console.log(option + " = " + value);  // This shows correct results;
    }
}
console.log(a.b.c) // when navigating to the options, the options have not changed from their integer values.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Yes, exactly, how can I update the value?

Comment: you may have to set a variable to the operation or pass in the object as the context https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach. Also you could probably find a way to do this without two forEach loops.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are just changing the value of the local variable to false/true, not changing the value of the object.

```js
var array = [{
  key: 1
}, {
  key: 0
}];
angular.forEach(array, function(options) {
  angular.forEach(options, function(value, option) {
    if (value == 0) {
      options[option] = false;
    } else {
      options[option] = true;
    }
    //the if else can be simplified to
    //options[option] = value != 0;
    console.log(option + " = " + options[option]);
  })
})

console.log(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

If you know the key to be updated then

```js
var array = [{
  key: 1
}, {
  key: 0
}];
angular.forEach(array, function(options) {
  options.key = options.key != 0;
})

console.log(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```